# Java Code modularization, check if they are all null or not

Tags: java

Is there any clean way to check if they are all null or not for example getDescription(), getName(), getScript(), getTargets() and getTrigger() is null or not, checking in one line?

````
              ruleBean.setDescription(rule.getDescription());
          } else if (rule.getName() != null) {
              ruleBean.setName(rule.getName());
          } else if (rule.getScript() != null) {
              ruleBean.setScript(rule.getScript());
          } else if (rule.getTargets() != null) {
              ruleBean.setTargets(rule.getTargets());
          } else if (rule.getTrigger() != null) {
              ruleBean.setTrigger(rule.getTrigger());
          } else {
              return ResponseBean.builder().withData(request.getData())
                      .withMessage("No data provided for rule update").asFailure().build();
          } ```
````

Comment: If the values you are getting in `string` type data, you can use `org.apache.commons.lang3` library, it has `StringUtils` class. it has methods like `isBlank()` , `isEmpty()`

Comment: Do you really mean to use `else if`? Once one non null property is found, the other properties are ignored.

Comment: is there anything that will check for all? like getName() getScript() getTargets() getTrigger() is null or not?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking for. Do you need to check that they are all non null? Or do you want to set all the non null properties of `rule` on `ruleBean`?

Comment: I don't think you can improve on what you have without substantially changing some other part of the code.  And *overall* that probably won't be an improvement.  My advice: don't over-think it.  And don't treat writing coding like writing poetry.

Comment: "checking in one line" reducing things to one line is not necessarily a desirable goal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can write a single condition with `Optional`:

```
if (rule.getName() != null) {
 ruleBean.setName(rule.getName());
}
```

becomes:

```
Optional.ofNullable(rule.getName()).ifPresent(ruleBean::setName);
```

It's harder to chain this to give the "if else" behaviour you have, though.

It looks like what you're trying to detect with the "if/else" is whether *some* update was performed. To achieve this, you could have a method like:

```
<T> boolean did(T value, Consumer<? super T> consumer) {
  if (value == null) return false;
  consumer.accept(value);
  return true;
}
```

Then you can write your chain as:

```
boolean didSomething =
    did(rule.getName(), ruleBean::setName)
    || did(rule.getScript(), ruleBean::setScript) /* etc */;

if (!didSomething) {
  // Return your error response.
}
```

Because of the short-circuiting behaviour of `||`, this will stop after the first call to `did` which "did" something, like the if/else if.

And if you actually want to apply the update for any non-null value, simply change `||` to `|`. The value of `didSomething` is still false if none of the conditions matched, as before.

Comment: `consumer.apply(value)` should be `consumer.accept(value)`, maybe a typo?

Answer (score 3):

[Java validation API](https://beanvalidation.org/2.0/) (JSR-380) can be very handy in this type of problems, if you can afford the dependencies.

In this specific case, you can just annotate your bean:

```java
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
// ...
public class Rule {

    @NotNull
    private String description;
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    @NotNull
    private String script;
    @NotNull
    private String targets;
    @NotNull
    private String trigger;

}
```

(there are more [built-in constraint definitions](https://beanvalidation.org/2.0/spec/#builtinconstraints))

And then validate using Hibernate Validator (the reference implementation of the validation API):

```java
        Rule rule = new Rule();
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Rule>> violations = validator.validate(rule);
        if (violations.isEmpty()) {
            //all good!
        } else {
            //bean is not valid
        }
```

In order to use this approach, you need two new dependencies in your pom.xml:

Java Validation API:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

and Hibernate Validator

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.13.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

- If you have a lot of attributes in `rule` need to check, you can use `reflection` to make it clean a little.
- If you just have a few attributes need to check, the `if` solution is a clean and readable way to do it.
- Waring: the `reflection` solution may lead to a performance issue.

#### example code:

```
test.java
public class test{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Foo rule = new Foo();
        Foo ruleBean = new Foo();
        rule.setName("foo");
        rule.setTargets(1);

        # the field you need to check, not necessary to check all attributes.
        List<String> fields = Arrays.asList("Name", "Script", "Targets");
        for (String field : fields) {
            try {
                Object temp = rule.getClass().getMethod("get"+field).invoke(rule);
                if (temp != null) {
                    ruleBean.getClass().getMethod("set"+field,temp.getClass()).invoke(ruleBean,temp);
                }
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        System.out.println(ruleBean.getName());
        System.out.println(ruleBean.getScript());
        System.out.println(ruleBean.getTargets());
    }
}


Foo.java

public class Foo {
    private String name;
    private String script;
    private Integer targets;

    public void setName(String s) {
        this.name = s;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setScript(String s) {
        this.script = s;
    }
    public String getScript() {
        return this.script;
    }

    public void setTargets(Integer s) {
        this.targets = s;
    }
    public Integer getTargets() {
        return this.targets;
    }

}
```

#### result:

```
foo
null
1
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that reflection should only be used as a last resort or if you do not care about the performance of the code.

Comment: Also if you don't care about compile-time safety.